# x86 assembly language rotate bits of characters to encrypt / obfuscate

Tags: assembly, encryption, x86, bit-shift

I am trying to make an application that can encrypt and decrypt a string with assembly language using the ROR/ROL instructions to encrypt/decrypt.
I use the following code to encrypt using an array of char to encrypt:

```
    push EAX
    push EBX
    push ECX
    push EDX

    MOV ECX, ArraySize
    LEA EDI, CharArray

    CICLE :
    MOV EAX, [EDI]
        ROR EAX, 03
        MOV[EDI], EAX
        INC EDI
        LOOP CICLE

        pop EDX
        pop ECX
        pop EBX
        pop EAX
```

I have tried to use the same method to decrypt but using ROL instead of ROR and in this case using the encrypted text resulting from the previous method as input, but it throws me a different text and not the original.

Comment: You've tagged your question as [tag:x86-16], but are using 32-bit registers everywhere. Are you intentionally loading and rotating 4 characters, not just 1?

Comment: @ThomasJager Sorry, I fixed it. I am loading an array of characters that can be any size and each character rotates with the loop

Comment: Why are you not using the 8-bit part of the register, and are using the full 32 bits instead?

Comment: Or more simply, `ror byte ptr [edi], 3`.  Like Thomas said, rotating bits between bytes is more complicated.  To undo overlapping dword rotates with the pointer incrementing by only 1 byte, you'd probably have to start with the *last* dword, i.e. loop in the opposite direction.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am very new to this and there are many details that I am overlooking. I didn't think about that, but once I tried the solution it worked perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: Note that this is barely encryption by modern standards, just mild obfuscation.  Encryption would imply that it was difficult for a clever human to figure out what's going on and reverse it themselves.  Rotating bits between bytes is more obscure than just rotating within each character like Sep's answer shows how to do, though.

Comment: Thank you. The application is a practice for academic purposes to learn the basics of encryption through assembler.

Comment: It's a very simple practice, we rotate bits to one side to "encrypt" and then do the same rotation in reverse to "decrypt".

Comment: Yeah, I understand how this works, and that you're calling it encryption.  I'm just saying it's so simplistic it barely counts as encryption these days.  It does make ASCII text not look like ASCII anymore (unlike ROT13), so `strings` won't find it in a binary, similar to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memfrob.3.html (XOR with `42`), so like that man page says, basically just obfuscation, a joke as far as actual security compared to something like TEA (https://www.nayuki.io/page/tiny-encryption-algorithm-in-x86-assembly), let alone AES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am loading an array of characters that can be any size and each character rotates with the loop

You get a different text back from decrypting because the encrypting is using mixed operand sizes between the rotation itself and the stepping through the array. You change a **dword** but you only advance by a **byte**. That's what makes the process *irreversible*!

Depending on the character size use:

```
; bytes
CICLE :
  ror  byte ptr [edi], 3
  inc  edi
  dec  ecx
  jnz  CICLE
```

or

```
; words
CICLE :
  ror  word ptr [edi], 3
  add  edi, 2
  dec  ecx
  jnz  CICLE
```

or

```
; dwords
CICLE :
  ror  dword ptr [edi], 3
  add  edi, 4
  dec  ecx
  jnz  CICLE
```

---

Don't `push` / `pop` registers that the code doesn't use or that don't need to be preserved.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been working on this for a short time which makes me ignore some details. Thanks for the recommendations, the application now does the encryption and decryption as it should, there are only some characters that do not return like "d", "t" or "4", is there a reason why this happens?

Comment: @Sep: It's not irreversible; you can reverse it just by looping the pointer in the other direction when undoing it, so you do the exact opposite sequence of moving bits between bytes.  (Assuming you left 3 bytes of padding past the end of the array, or that they're part of the ciphertext needed to "decrypt" this mild obfuscation.)  The querent [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71904953/x86-assembly-language-encryption/71905638#comment127062433_71904953) that worked.  I suspect you're right that the overlapping 4-byte block-size was an unintentional design, though.

Comment: @GreyJacket: `ror byte ptr [edi], 3` is the exact inverse of `rol byte ptr [edi], 3` for any bit-pattern.  If some byte values are getting munged, that's a separate bug in your program.  (Perhaps due to overwriting at their position, not due to some problem with that particular value.  i.e. some bugs would step on any character in that position, whether it's a `'d'` or `'X'`).  Anyway, certainly outside the scope of the problem you're asking about with the code in this Q&A.

Comment: @GreyJacket The characters that you report *not returning* have ASCII codes  64h, 74h, and 34h. Rotating these 3 times to the right produces what is called an extended ASCII (one that has its highest bit ON). Perhaps your visualization tool doesn't do a great job at showing those?

Comment: @SepRoland This is probably why, I will find a way to make the application not have a problem with those extended ASCII characters or I will rotate them less so that they are returned correctly. Thank you again, greetings.

Comment: @GreyJacket: How are you round-tripping your "encrypted" characters in/out of your application?  If you're trying to copy/paste them, a terminal that uses UTF-8 instead of an 8-bit character set might be a problem.  If you're saving to a binary file, then all your handling of the "ciphertext" is just treating it as binary data and can't mess it up.  (Displaying the bit-rotated characters might not show anything meaningful on a terminal, but you shouldn't expect it to because it' not ASCII text anymore.)